# container with both unique elements and access by index

Tags: c++, stl, containers

**It seemed unclear what exactly I wanted, so I reworded the question**

There are containers where each element is unique (e.g. [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)), however with those I am unable to access elements by index (e.g. get a single object out of the container), like this:

```
std::set<Object> set {obj1, obj2};
Object o = set[0]; // does not work
```

So to have a container with access by index capabilities (e.g. [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)) that only stores unique elements, I have to manually make sure that all elements within the container are unique, like this:

```
std::vector<Object> vec { ... }; // vector with some objects
// adding an object
if (std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), obj) == 0) {
    vec.push_back(obj);
} else {
    std::cout << "object already in container!\n";
}
```

Surely traversing the whole container each time I add an object can be expensive, so I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Extract? You mean remove, read, or what?

Comment: @Adrian May: I mean, get an Object and use it otherwise.

Comment: You can do that with the set as well.

Comment: @Jagannath: But it doesn't have an at() function or uses the [] operators?

Comment: I still don't know what you mean. How about if you write your fantasy code with an ideal collection called fantasy<whatever> and then we might know what you're trying to do

Comment: Are you looking to map one thing onto another, like with map<> ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find

Comment: @Adrian May: I edited my question. No, I only have a key, no value.

Comment: You don't find / get the data out of set by using index. As I gave the link in the above comment, use find().

Comment: @Jagannath: This only gives me an iterator.

Comment: @Jagannath: Yes, exactly, that's why I'm asking if there's a container that does what I want, or if I manually need to make sure that there are no duplicates.

Comment: But in your code I'd say idx was an index and o was a value, so it sounds like a map. Otherwise you'd just write o=idx and there'd be no need for the collection.

Comment: @Adrian May: Oh you mean like a map<unsigned int, Object>? But then I have to manually look what's the next index when inserting something, I thought there was something easier.

Comment: @gartenriese Your understanding of std::set and std::map is wrong. You don't insert the keys at the "next index".

Comment: @Jagannath: Well, if I want access by index, I need an index, right? I only wanted to make sure I understood Adrian May correctly. But I guess I didn't. I didn't think a map was suitable anyways, see my third edit.

Comment: Why don't you tell us the bigger picture.

Comment: @Adrian May: I reworded the whole question, hope it's clear now!

Comment: Still not clear to me. On the one hand you say you want it unique and on the other you complain about making it unique. Neither do I know whether you want to store a bag of things or a map from keys to things. I meant tell us the BIG picture. What's it for?

Comment: @Adrian May: I definitely want it unique, see the title of the question. I never complain about making it unique, I am complaining about that the containers that support uniqueness don't support element access by index. I never said that I want to store a map from keys to things, I only have objects. And I want to use it for A*.

Comment: But still I keep asking you for the bigger picture cos I bet your objects have got some unique field in them, in which case why not map from that instead of from integers. Is there some reason you want to map from integers, which is basically what a vector is. If you wrote that "count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), obj)" then you'd need a comparison operator, right, so what would it be? Or would you just compare the pointer values and allow two objects that were identical on the inside?

Comment: @Adrian May: Yes, the objects have all their own ID. That's how I compare them. If I use a map, I still can't access the elements by index. As I said before, I can't use a map or a set because they both don't allow element access by index.

Comment: But you didn't say why you want to access them by index. Why not map from the ID?

Comment: @Adrian May: I want to access them by index, so that I can get e.g. the first element in the container.

Comment: That's tautological. Why is there a concept of 'first' in your data?

Comment: So that I can sort them, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own container. Something like:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template<class OBJ>
class idx_set
{
public:
  // ...

 bool insert(const OBJ &o)
 {
   if (set_.find(o) == set_.end())
   {
     set_.insert(o);
     vect_.push_back(o);
     return true;
   }

   return false;
 }

 const OBJ &operator[](unsigned i) const { return vect_[i]; }

 // ...

private:
  std::set<OBJ> set_;
  std::vector<OBJ> vect_;
};

int main()
{
  idx_set<int> im;

  assert(im.insert(10));
  assert(im.insert(12));
  assert(!im.insert(10));

  std::cout << im[0] << im[1] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

- adding new elements (O(logN) complexity) won't change the index of existing elements.

  Insertion complexity can be lowered changing the `std::set` with a [std::unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)
- accessing elements via index is fast (O(1) complexity).

  Note that a solution based on `std::map<unsigned, OBJ>` would be simpler but slower in this regard.
- it's not too complex to code

but of course you are sacrificing memory for speed.

Comment: Yes, that's practically what I do right now, I have a vector and I check if a element is already in it before adding it to the vector. I wouldn't need a set though in your example.

Comment: Checking if a element exists in the unordered vector is slower: O(N) vs O(log N) (or O(1) using a `std:unordered_set`).

Comment: Ah, okay, that's smart! :)